# Configuring the timeout for a WCF RIA Services call from a Silverlight 3 client

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm using the [WCF RIA Services Beta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344(VS.91).aspx) with Silverlight 3.0 and I want to be able to configure the timeout from the client. I know that the underlying technology is WCF and the default timeout seems to be 60 seconds as I would expect.

Is there an easy way to control this and other WCF settings?

My first thought is to try the [DomainContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.ria.domaincontext_members(VS.91).aspx) **OnCreated** hook point which was mentioned in the **RIA Services Overview** pdf file that was available prior to RIA Services going beta. The MSDN documentation for the [DomainContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.ria.domaincontext_members(VS.91).aspx) object no longer mentions the method although it is still there? I'm not sure if this is a case of the documentation lagging behind or an indication that I shouldn't use this extensibility point.

```
namespace Example.UI.Web.Services
{
    public sealed partial class CustomDomainContext
    {
        partial void OnCreated()
        {
            // Try and get hold of the WCF config from here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blogs.objectsharp.com/CS/blogs/dan/archive/2010/03/22/changing-timeouts-in-wcf-ria-services-rc.aspx

Either one line after domain context creation:

```
((WebDomainClient<LibraryDomainContext.ILibraryDomainServiceContract>)this.DomainClient).ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
```

or a partial class

```
public partial class LibraryDomainContext
{
   partial void OnCreated()
   {
      if(DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(App.Current.RootVisual))
         ((WebDomainClient<LibraryDomainContext.ILibraryDomainServiceContract>)this.DomainClient).ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not working on this code base any longer but it's good to know they exposed this eventually. I was working with the Beta at the time.

Comment: BTW This doesn't work with RTM, or at least I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Here is an update working with silverlight 4: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/11/03/how-to-change-the-request-timeout-for-wcf-ria-services.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For reference the code below *nearly* works but you can't access a private member using reflection in Silverlight. Wouldn't have been happy with this **hack** though anyway. Interesting to note that there is a WebDomainClient contructor that takes a Binding parameter `private WebDomainClient(Uri serviceUri, bool usesHttps, Binding binding)` but the XML Comment for this states *Private constructor. Should be made public once we have an end-to-end extensibility story on top of WCF*. Looks like I'll have to wait a while before they get to exposing this kind of configuration to us.

```
public sealed partial class AppDomainContext
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        var webDomainClient = ((WebDomainClient<AppDomainContext.IAppDomainServiceContract>)this.DomainClient);
        // Can I use reflection here to get hold of the Binding
        var bindingField = webDomainClient.GetType().GetField("_binding", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // In Silverlight, the value of a private field cannot be access by using reflection so the GetValue call throws an exception
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e%28VS.95%29.aspx
        var binding = bindingField.GetValue(webDomainClient) as System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding;

        // So near yet so far!!
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do we can configure it via web.config?