# WCF ria service SP1 timeout expired

Tags: entity-framework-4, timeout, wcf-ria-services

My solution is Silverlight which uses WCF RIA service SP1 and Entity Framework 4.

I have a problem with loading large size data.

I've got this error message.

> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainException : Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I think that it's a problem regards with timeout, so I tried below code. It worked when I hadn't install WCF Ria service "SP1". 
But it's not working since I've installed "SP1".

```
ChannelFactory<BatchContext.IBatchServiceContract> channel = ((WebDomainClient<BatchContext.IBatchServiceContract>)this.DomainClient).ChannelFactory;
channel.Endpoint.Binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);  
channel.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);    
channel.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);    
channel.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain my context and I wish it will work for my. I'm sure about that.

First of all to call RIA services, and using some domain context, in my example:

```
EmployeeDomainContext context = new EmployeeDomainContext();
InvokeOperation<bool> invokeOperation = context.GenerateTMEAccessByEmployee(1, 'Bob');
invokeOperation.Completed += (s, x) =>
    {....};
```

Nothing new until here. And with this I was facing every time that same timeout exception after 1 minute. I spend quite a lot of time trying to face how to change the timeout definition, I tried all possible changes in Web.config and nothing. The solution was:

Create a CustomEmployeeDomainContext, that is a partial class **localizated in the same path of the generated code** and this class use the hook method OnCreate to change the behavior of created domain context. In this class you should wrote:

```
public partial class EmployeeDomainContext : DomainContext
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        PropertyInfo channelFactoryProperty = this.DomainClient.GetType().GetProperty("ChannelFactory");
        if (channelFactoryProperty == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
              "There is no 'ChannelFactory' property on the DomainClient.");
        }

        ChannelFactory factory = (ChannelFactory)channelFactoryProperty.GetValue(this.DomainClient, null);

        factory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0); 

    }
}
```

I looking forward for you feedback.