# Increase Timeout in silverlight application

Tags: wcf, silverlight, timeout

I have a silverlight 4 application with RIA service enabled, also the silverlight uses a WCF service and the whole things are hosted on IIS.
I need to increase the timeout of the silverlight for the WCF service and ria services, and IIS 7.5.
How can I set the releated timeout settings (ria services, WCF, IIS)?
P.S

where are the correspoding fields in the configuration?

Comment: If you could post the error message it would be easier to help.  The web site request could timeout while transferring a lot of data (IIS/web.config setting).   Or the database connection could time out while querying a large data set (SQL command setting).   What is the error message you're receiving?

Comment: I'm asking about where I can configure the timeout, wherever exists (asp.net, IIS, ria services, wcf services, silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I posted the answer to this question here: [Silverlight 4 WCF RIA Service Timeout Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150493/silverlight-4-wcf-ria-service-timeout-problem/12483889#12483889)

**Here is the answer:**

I answered the same question here: [WCF ria service SP1 timeout expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811944/wcf-ria-service-sp1-timeout-expired/12483872#12483872)

The answer:

I'll explain my context and I wish it will work for my. I'm sure about that.

First of all to call RIA services, and using some domain context, in my example:

```
EmployeeDomainContext context = new EmployeeDomainContext();
InvokeOperation<bool> invokeOperation = context.GenerateTMEAccessByEmployee(1, 'Bob');
invokeOperation.Completed += (s, x) =>
    {....};
```

Nothing new until here. And with this I was facing every time that same timeout exception after 1 minute. I spend quite a lot of time trying to face how to change the timeout definition, I tried all possible changes in Web.config and nothing. The solution was:

Create a CustomEmployeeDomainContext, that is a partial class **localizated in the same path of the generated code** and this class use the hook method OnCreate to change the behavior of created domain context. In this class you should wrote:

```
public partial class EmployeeDomainContext : DomainContext
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        PropertyInfo channelFactoryProperty = this.DomainClient.GetType().GetProperty("ChannelFactory");
        if (channelFactoryProperty == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
              "There is no 'ChannelFactory' property on the DomainClient.");
        }

        ChannelFactory factory = (ChannelFactory)channelFactoryProperty.GetValue(this.DomainClient, null);

        factory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0); 

    }
}
```

I looking forward for you feedback.