# Configure DomainContext Client Timeout

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria

In a Silverlight 4 app, I would like to increase the timeout for a specific RIA service load operation (not for all loads, just in a specific case).  At  [Configuring the timeout for a WCF RIA Services call from a Silverlight 3 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912762/configuring-the-timeout-for-a-wcf-ria-services-call-from-a-silverlight-3-client) I followed a link to instructions that purportedly would allow me to set the timeout.

It appeared to work fine (no compiler error, warning, exception, etc) except that the load operation still timed out early.  It appears that with or without the code that modifies the endpoint the load operation is timing out after 2 minutes.  There is an Opening event on the ChannelFactory which I subscribed to, and my handler was called at the start of the load operation, so that seems to confirm that the ChannelFactory is being used.  Also I set all 4 timeout values (Receive, Open, Close, Send) to 10 minutes just to be sure that I wasn't setting the wrong one.

Why I am unable to actually change the timeout for the RIA load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem was that multiple timeouts were in play.  I was using an EntityFramework domain service for RIA, and I was getting an EntityFramework timeout.  I was misinterpreting the source of the timeout as being from the RIA load until I noticed in the stack trace that the timeout was server side.  I extended the allotted EntityFramework command timeout to fit my desired load behavior.  I was able to confirm that after getting a reference to the channel factory for the domain context I could set the RIA client-side timeout.

NOTE TO SELF: a good way to troubleshoot a timeout is to start by setting it really short to confirm it is working as intended